# Use ajax to call ActionResult with value from text box.

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

The only field that the user updates is **QuantityDelivered**, then the user clicks the Accept Button to update the number entered in the textbox and the ShoeOrderItem via Ajax.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ShoeOrderItemList.Count(); i++)
{
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].ShoeOrderItemId)
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].ShoeOrderItemId)
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].LineItemTotal)
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].ShoeSize.Size)
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].Shoe.ManufacturingCost)
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].Quantity)
    </td>
    <td class="text-center">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].QuantityOutstanding)
    </td>
    <td>
        @(Html.Bootstrap().TextBoxFor(m => m.QuantityDelivered)
          .Placeholder("Quantity Delivered ")
          .Prepend("#").Append(Html.Bootstrap()
          .Button().Text("Accept").Id("AcceptItem")))
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Ajax

```
$("#AcceptItem").click(function() {
  var quatntity = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.QuantityDelivered))
  $.ajax({
     url: "ShoeOrder/CreateShoeDelivery",
     type: "GET",
     data: {
            shoeOrderItemId: shoeOrderItemId[i],
            quantityDelivered: quatntity,
            dataType: "html"
        }
    });
});
```

I would just like to call the ActionResult with the value entered by the user when they click the button AcceptItem.

Answer (score 1):

> I would just like to call the ActionResult with the value entered by
>   the user when they click the button AcceptItem.

Follow this solution -

Say you have following form. Please give proper id's to input fields and notice I made a POST operation.

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function submitForm() {

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("Submit")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ name: $("#quantity").val() }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Name);
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="text" id="quantity"/>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

On clicking the button would hit Submit Action -

```
    public ActionResult Submit(string name)
    {
        return Json(new Person() { Name = name + " Its Me" });
    }
```

and the action would simply return a simple object of Person (I used it for example purpose).

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Now when you click on the button -

[image]

If you want to make a GET operation, then JQuery code should be like this -

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "@Url.Action("Submit")" + "/" + $("#quantity").val(),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "", //JSON.stringify({ name: $("#quantity").val() }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.Name);
    },
    failure: function (errMsg) {
        alert(errMsg);
    }
});
```

}

Do not forget to add AllowGet to JsonResponse -

```
    public ActionResult Submit(string id)
    {
        return Json(new Person() { Name = id + " Its Me" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need to pass the `shoeOrderItemId` from the hidden field and the `quantity` entered into the text box by the user `@Html.DisplayFor(model => Model.ShoeOrderItemList[i].Quantity)`. Would the best solution be to use a form like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22013660/pass-entity-from-view-to-controller/22014301#22014301